# Stopping execution in refactored php code?

Tags: php, oop, testing, refactoring

I have just refactored a php page to make it slightly easier to extend and maintain in the future and gotten stuck on quite a simple problem.

I have broken one method up into 3.

largemethod() has become something like this:

```
nowsmallmethod(){
  doSomeChecks();
  assignProduct();
  giveFeedbacktoUser();
}
```

This is all good and well, the problem I am having is with doSomeChecks();

```
doSomeChecks(){
 if(something that shouldnt be true is true){
    return Controller->redirectBk();
 }
}
```

The crux of the problem is that Controller-redirectBk first redirects when nowsmallmethod() has been completed. This means that the user is assigned a product even if a test fails. I am using a php framework called Silverstripe so I cant really change the behavior of Controller->redirectBk(). If I didnt have the checks in their own method then everything would work fine because the "return Controller->redirectBk();" would stop execution and redirect back. **Whats the best way to stop execution in nowsmallmethod() when a test fails?** I realise i could return a status code for an error and then stop execution but it seems an ugly way. Is there not a more elegant way? Another option would be if i could return something like this in doSomeChecks(), "return (return $controller->redirectBk())" but this is not valid php syntax and not particularly easy to read. Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Enjoy your weekend!
Cheers
Nick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
nowsmallmethod() {
  if (doSomeChecks()) {
    assignProduct();
    giveFeedbacktoUser();
  }
}
```

And `doSomeChecks` either returns true or false, based on whether the redirect will happen or not.

Alternatively, you could `die` or `throw`, but I assume a normal condition is more suitable in your case.

Comment: This is really functionally equivalent of returning an error code. I just thought there might be a better way to do it but maybe not. In this case any failed test would have to set $controller->redirectBk() then return false. cheers for your suggestion

Answer (score 1):

Use exceptions to handle situations like that:

```
<?php
try {
    // some code
    if (!$check) {
         throw new Exception('Check has failed!');
    }
    // code after 'throw' will not be executed
} 
catch(Exception $e) {
    //this is executed when exception is caught
}
?>
```

If the exception is thrown in child method, the stack will roll back to the very first try/catch block. read more about the exceptions: http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php

Also, you can combine exceptions with transaction mechanism to handle database integrity.

Comment: Exceptions are for abnormal situations like where you try to get some resource and fail. I don't think this is the case.

Comment: Hey thanks for your suggestion. There are a couple of checks in there that throw exceptions, security tests etc. But the majority set a userfeedback session message and then simply return that message to the user. They are not really suited for exceptions.